# Why do I get an grade output of F every time?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

The entire code runs, and the first half works (ie the <40 part), but if it gets to the else part, it only ever gives a grade of F.

```
w = input("Input Student ID:")
x = int(input("Input Assignment Score:"))
y = int(input("Input Midterm Score:"))

if (x + y)/2 < 40:
    print(w + ": F Without Final")
else:
    z = int(input("Input Final Score:"))
    if (.25 * x + .25 * y + .5 * z)/3 < 50:
        print(w + ": F")
    elif (.25 * x + .25 * y + .5 * z)/3 < 60:
        print(w + ": D")
    elif (.25 * x + .25 * y + .5 * z)/3 < 70:
        print(w + ": C")
    elif (.25 * x + .25 * y + .5 * z)/3 < 80:
        print(w + ": B")
    else:
        print(w + ": A")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a weighted average in the second part; remove the `/3` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Don't divide the result by 3 on each if statement

```
w = input("Input Student ID:")
x = int(input("Input Assignment Score:"))
y = int(input("Input Midterm Score:"))

if (x + y)/2 < 40:
    print(w + ": F Without Final")
else:
    z = int(input("Input Final Score:"))
    if (.25 * x + .25 * y + .5 * z) < 50:
        print(w + ": F")
    elif (.25 * x + .25 * y + .5 * z) < 60:
        print(w + ": D")
    elif (.25 * x + .25 * y + .5 * z) < 70:
        print(w + ": C")
    elif (.25 * x + .25 * y + .5 * z) < 80:
        print(w + ": B")
    else:
        print(w + ": A")
```